# Alert of vars returns "length" or "item"

Tags: javascript, html, dom, lambda

I have a 16x16 table, and I asign a lambda function (to pass parameters to the actually functional function) to all the td like that:

```
function handlerAsignment()
{
    var trs = document.getElementsByTagName("tr");
    var tds;

    for (tr in trs) {
        tds = trs[tr].getElementsByTagName("td");

        for (td in tds){
            tds[td].onclick = function() {
                atack(tr, td);
            };
        }
    }
}
```

As you will see, I have to pass the tr number and the td number regarding to the proper tr.
But then I have this function:

```
function atack(tr, td)
{
   alert("Tr: " +tr+ " td: " +td);
}
```

And this show me the message "Tr: item td: length". **Why???**

**Advice:** I don't want to use event in the *function atack* to detect the correct td. I need this parameters to acces and work properly with a 16x16 multidimensional array (equal to the table, but with more information).

Comment: FWIW, "assignment" has two "s"s in it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the classic closure misunderstanding. The function (closure) you're assigning to `onclick` has an *enduring reference* to the `tr` and `td` variables, not a *copy* of them as of when it was created. So all of the `onclick` functions use the same variables, with the same values; the values as they are at the *end* of both loops.

The usual answer here is to use a builder function so they use separate variables:

```
function handlerAsignment()
{
    var trs = document.getElementsByTagName("tr");
    var tds;

    for (tr in trs) {
        tds = trs[tr].getElementsByTagName("td");

        for (td in tds){
            tds[td].onclick = buildHandler(tr, td);
        }
    }
}

function buildHandler(tr, td) {
    return function() {
        atack(tr, td);
    };
}
```

Now, the handler closes over the `tr` and `td` arguments passed into `buildHandler`, not the `tr` and `td` variables used in the loop. Since those arguments never change (each call to `buildHandler` gets its own), it solves the problem.

More on my blog: [*Closures are not complicated*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/02/closures-are-not-complicated.html)

---

Two other things worth mentioning:

1. You're not declaring `td` or `tr` anywhere, so you're falling prey to [*The Horror of Implicit Globals*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html)
2. You don't use `for-in` to loop through `NodeList` instances. `for-in` loops through the property names of objects. Using it with host-provided objects like `NodeList` is not guaranteed to work, and moreover relies on the host-provided object making some things enumerable and other things non-enumerable. Use a standard loop instead. So:

   ```
   function handlerAsignment()
   {
     var trs = document.getElementsByTagName("tr");
     var tds;
     var trIndex, tdIndex;

     for (trIndex = 0; trIndex < trs.length; ++trIndex) {
       tds = trs[trIndex].getElementsByTagName("td");

       for (tdIndex = 0; tdIndex < tds.length; ++tdIndex){
         tds[tdIndex].onclick = buildHandler(trIndex, tdIndex);
       }
     }
   }

   function buildHandler(tr, td) {
     return function() {
       atack(tr, td);
     };
   }
   ```

   More: [*Myths and realities of `for..in`*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2010/11/myths-and-realities-of-forin.html)

   [Live Example](http://jsbin.com/isAgedET/1) | [Source](http://jsbin.com/isAgedET/1/edit)

Finally, if you can rely on having the `Array#forEach` function from ECMAScript5 (e.g., you know your target browsers have it, or you're using a shim for it), the code can be simpler because `forEach` gives you the equivalent of `buildHandler` (a set of arguments to close over) for free:

```
function handlerAsignment()
{
  var trs = document.getElementsByTagName("tr");
  var tds;
  var forEach = Array.prototype.forEach;

  forEach.call(trs, function(tr, trIndex) {
    forEach.call(tr.getElementsByTagName("td"), function(td, tdIndex) {
      td.onclick = function() {
        atack(trIndex, tdIndex);
      };
    });
  });
}
```

[Live Example](http://jsbin.com/isAgedET/2) | [Source](http://jsbin.com/isAgedET/2/edit)

You can safely use `Array#forEach` on any array-like object, not just arrays. `NodeList` objects are array-like.

Comment: The problem is more that in most sensible languages, the default way of looping would make `tr` and `td` distinct variables each time through, so the closure would capture the right thing regardless. In JavaScript, you have to use `Array.forEach` to accomplish that (through function parameter binding).

Comment: @hobbs: No, languages with closures typically behave *exactly* like this, it's incredibly useful when understood properly.

Comment: No, languages with closures typically have lexical scope that works properly, which lets you *make the choice*, instead of JavaScript's deficient scoping. In an alternate universe where JS was sane, `var x; for (x in xs) { ... function() { x } ... }` would behave one way, while `for (var x in xs) { ... function () { x } ... }` would behave the other. But JS forces you to express the latter as `for (var x in xs) { ... (function (_x) { return function() { _x })(x) ... }` instead.

Comment: Anyway, all of this is semi-irrelevant; see my answer for the more fundamental problem, which is that `for (tr in trs)` doesn't do anything useful with or without your suggestion.

Comment: @hobbs: I cover that as well. Re the other thing, I'm not rising.

Comment: It wasn't there when I wrote :)

Comment: @hobbs: No, unlike you I only noticed it when I went off to do a live example, saw `for (tr in trs)`, and went "uh oh." :-)

Answer (score 1):

`for (tr in trs)` isn't the thing you want. It sets `tr` to *the name of each property* of `trs` in turn. Since `trs` is a `NodeList`, its named properties are `length` and its `item` method.

The `for (tr of trs)` syntax would work, but you're coding for the browser, and browser support for that isn't widespread.

A `NodeList` isn't a real array, so you can't easily use `Array.forEach` on it.

So, your best bet is using `for (var i = 0 ; i < trs.length ; i++)` plus `trs[i]` plus T.J.'s `buildHandler` trick to make sure that the variable your handler closes over doesn't change after the closure is created.

Comment: +1 I didn't catch the `for-in` until I went to do my live example. Came back to post it (which I did) and see you covered it as well.

Answer (score 1):

No one has discussed the elephant in the room: creating a handler that passes a reference to the element it's on is unnecessary since the handler can be set up to reference that element as *this* by default.

Similarly, passing a reference to that element's parent also makes no sense when that element is available as `this.parentNode`.

A  simple function to add listeners using either addEventListener or attachEvent as appropriate:

```
  function addListener(element, event, fn) {

    // Use addEventListener if available
    if (element.addEventListener) {
      element.addEventListener(event, fn, false);

    // Otherwise use attachEvent, set this and event
    } else if (element.attachEvent) {
      element.attachEvent('on' + event, (function (el) {
        return function() {
          fn.call(el, window.event);
        };
      }(element)));

      // Break closure and primary circular reference to element
      element = null;
    }
  }
```

Use the above to attach the listeners on the cells, then within the *atack* (*attack*?) function:

```
function atack(evt) {
  var cell = this;
  var row = cell.parentNode; 

  alert("Tr: " + row + " td: " + cell);
}
```

If you investigate event delegation you may find you only need a single listener on the table.

Comment: +1 for thinking about the better way to solve the problem rather than just the solution that was asked about.